# How to predict the probability of a discrete choice problem?

Tags: predictive-models, model-selection, logit, choice-modeling

I am looking for a **discrete choice model** (e.g. a logit) to describe the reaction of a pedestrian when a car is arriving. Depending on the severity of the conflict and other geometrical parameters, he has to decide what to do.

There are **input parameters** like: distance, speed of the car, acceleration of the car, time proximity to the collision. **Possible alternatives**: to stop and let the car pass (choice 1), to go undisturbed (choice 2), to decelerate to see if the car accord priority(choice 3).

I have a large amount of real world data (more than 1000 observations, N=1000) with input parameters and the relative decision he took (1,2, or 3).

**I would like to know, given a certain combination of the input parameter, what is the probability associated to every discrete choice** (cause everyone could react differently to the same input).

My personal difficulty: in a choice model every alternative has a disutility. Here I have only one disutility associated to the situation.

+-----------------------------+

**SUMMARIZING**

Sample N=1000

input variables: 6 (discrete or continuous)

outputvariable: 1 (discrete)

Aim: to estimate the probability, for a given combination of the 6 input variables, the probability to choose alternative A (as well as B and C)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the disutilities you are referring to?

Comment: Hi @gung. Assuming the preferred reaction is choice 2 (do not decelerate or react, but simply go), disutilities are e.g. proximity of the car (or the speed of the car) --> the more the car is close (or: the more the car is fast), the more I would tend to decelerate (take reaction 1 or 3).

Comment: I don't quite understand the disutility thing. But, it sounds like you want to fit a probabilitic classifier where the inputs are your variables and the output is a probability distribution over choices 1-3. If you believe the problem is linear, you can use multinomial logistic regression. Otherwise, you could use a multilayer neural net with softmax output. Or, many other classifiers (e.g. support vector machine, random forest) in conjunction with probability calibration (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html)